# Forbid automatic type inference

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I have following demonstration code:

```
template <int i, typename T, typename U>
T func(const U &t){return i * t;}

template <int i, typename T>
T func(const T &t){return 2 * i * t;}

int main()
{
        return func<1, int>(1);
}
```

Which is a boiled down version of my real code, so it seems useless but should suffice to show the problem:

```
In function ‘int main()’:                                                  
11:23: error: call of overloaded ‘func(int)’ is ambiguous
11:23: note: candidates are:
2:3: note: T func(const U&) [with int i = 1, T = int, U = int]
5:3: note: T func(const T&) [with int i = 1, T = int]
```

So it is clear that the automatic type inference (for template parameter U) interferes with my interests of picking the right version of the template function (which is the one that has only 2 parametrs)

I need both versions to have a basic and a specialized template, that do things a little different.

So the question is: Is there any possibility to tell the compiler not to infer the type automatically at this point (for example by somehow saying: Take the template that has only 2 parameters)?

Comment: You mean besides the obvious? (which is to give those to function templates different names - what's the point of having the same name if you need to do something yourself to instruct the compiler on which one to use?)

Comment: Well this would be the last choice but I would like the functions to share the same name.

Comment: I would also suggest a redesign by renaming. For me this seems like a very bad code smell. People already get confused easily by the question which function of a overloaded set is being used. If something like this is present it makes it even harder and might lead to unmaintainable code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an initializer list, which effectively disables deduction (but causes list-initialization of parameters which in this case of `int` has the same effect though):

```
template <int i, typename T, typename U>
T func(const U &t){return i * t;}

template <int i, typename T>
T func(const T &t){return 2 * i * t;}

int main()
{
        return func<1, int>({1});
}
```

But in your case, if you call `func<N>(...)` you seem to want to call the second one, and if you call `func<N, T>(...)` you always seem to want to call the second one too, and only for `func<N, T, U>(...)` you want to call the first one, so you can *always* disable deduction for `U` by making the parameter a nondeduced context for it

```
template <int i, typename T, typename U>
T func(typename std::common_type<const U &t>::type t){return i * t;}

template <int i, typename T>
T func(const T &t){return 2 * i * t;}

int main()
{
        return func<1, int>({1});
}
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I was asking for. Although I circumvented the problem now I think this suits the question much better.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable type inference, but you can use SFINAE to inhibit one of the overloads:

```
template <int N, typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<T,U>::value, T >::type
func( const U & t ) {
   return i*t;
}
```

That basically creates a templated function for which substitution will fail if the inferred type `U` is the type `T`, at which point SFINAE will remove the template from the set of potential candidates and the other template will be picked up.

If you don't have a C++11 enabled compiler, the `enable_if` and `is_same` templates are simple to write... just google for them or drop a comment.

Comment: This may solve my problem but it does not answer the question. Maybe you have an answer for this, too?

Comment: Type inference is part of the language, and you cannot just *disable* it. You can in some cases (as the one above) *disable* an overload so that it will not be considered under some circumstances.

Comment: Probably I should have used another wording. I did not mean the automatic type inference but the fact, that the template parameter is set automatically. So basically I was asking for a syntax that tells the compiler: Take the template with this parameter signature!

Comment: @Nobody: That is exactly *type inference*. Without type inference you would have to provide all of the template arguments, and in your case, because you have only two arguments, it would not have caused any ambiguity.